# How to query SQL in a loop in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

**SCENARIO:**
Using mssql I'm connecting to sql and retrieving a list of ids, then based on those id I want to run stored procedures. What I'm currently doing is running the first stored proc, storing the id's in an array, then I'm running a for loop calling another module, where I pass the id to run a stored proc. This works fine when I've got a single id, but fails with 'Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.' when I try to run multiple ones.

How do I create connect to sql, run my query, then run the next one? What's the best approach?

The code below runs the stored proc with ids and causes the above error.

```
exports.runStoredProc = function (query,id) {
    sql.connect(config.config).then(()=>{
        return sql.query`${query} ${id}`
      }).then(res=> {
        do something with the response    
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Looks like the connection still exists when the below bit of code runs it using next id. I thought that creating a Promise will force to await execution before it runs the above bit of code again?

```
let toRun = result.recordset.length
let gen = async num => {
  for(let i=0;i<num;i++) {
    var resp = result.recordset[i].id
    console.log(i, resp)
    var sp = report
    var reportId = await new Promise(() => db.runStoredProc(sp,resp))
  }        
}
gen(toRun).then(() => console.log("done!"))
```

Comment: ` = await new Promise(() => db.runStoredProc(sp,resp))` doesn't work. I'm not sure what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `Promise` from `runStoredProc`

```
exports.runStoredProc = function (query,id) {
    return sql.connect(config.config).then(()=>{
        return sql.query`${query} ${id}`
      }).then(res=> {
        do something with the response    
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

and no need to wrap `db.runStoredProc` in loop

```
let toRun = result.recordset.length
let gen = async num => {
  for(let i=0;i<num;i++) {
    var resp = result.recordset[i].id
    console.log(i, resp)
    var sp = report
    var reportId = await db.runStoredProc(sp,resp)
  }        
}
gen(toRun).then(() => console.log("done!"))
```